# How to use the DOMConfigurator for log4j while using the slf4j?

Tags: java, logging, log4j, slf4j

I am trying to use slf4j with log4j and I am having some difficulty in using the log4j config xml. How can i use the config xmls for log4j with slf4j. Please guide me.

LoggerImpl Implementation class:

```
package com.cisco.logger.LoggerFramework;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;


public class LoggerImpl implements ILogger {

    public Logger getLogger(Class name) {

        Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(name);
        return logger;

    }


}
```

Log4j Config XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">

<!-- ===================================================================== -->
<!--                                                                       -->
<!--  Log4j Configuration                                                  -->
<!--                                                                       -->
<!-- ===================================================================== -->

<!-- $Id: log4j.xml,v 1.1.1.1 2005/11/12 20:08:29 gmoran Exp $ -->

<!--
   | For more configuration information and examples see the Jakarta Log4j
   | owebsite: http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j
-->

<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/" debug="false">

   <!-- ================================= -->
   <!-- Preserve messages in a local file -->
   <!-- ================================= -->

   <!-- A time/date based rolling appender -->
   <appender name="LOGGERFILE" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">

      <param name="File" value="/apps/pentaho_nfs/installbase/input/poc/applogger.log"/>
      <param name="Append" value="false"/>

      <!-- Rollover at midnight each day -->
      <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd"/>

      <!-- Rollover at the top of each hour
      <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH"/>
      -->

      <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
         <!-- The default pattern: Date Priority [Category] Message\n -->
         <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p [%c] %m%n"/>

         <!-- The full pattern: Date MS Priority [Category] (Thread:NDC) Message\n
         <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5r %-5p [%c] (%t:%x) %m%n"/>
          -->
      </layout>
   </appender>

   <root>
      <priority value="ALL" />
      <appender-ref ref="LOGGERFILE"/>
   </root>


</log4j:configuration>
```

Comment: see here http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html. for a detailed answer, you will need to be a bit more specific (i.e what 'difficulties' do you have?)